# Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::Store::NestedTransactionError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, macos, react-native

I developed an application with ReactNative and RubyOnRails.
I have struggled with the error described below for ten days.

I initialized my Mac with the following packages:

```
Software/Versions
  Ruby '2.5.1'
  Rails 5.2.1
  bootsnap (1.3.1)
```

The `/config/boot.rb` contains:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
require 'bundler/setup' 
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' 
# Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

The terminal displays the following error message:

```
#<Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::Store::NestedTransactionError: 
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::Store::NestedTransactionError>
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:43:in `transaction'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:130:in `push_paths_locked'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:113:in `block in 
reinitialize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `reinitialize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:46:in `find'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:28:in
`require'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/
activesupport 
#<LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/backtrace_cleaner>
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
```

Comment: It happens to me when I switch from a Rails 5.1.7 branch of my application to a branch with the previous version (RoR 4.2.7).
The problem seems related to cookies (maybe session?) since if I force a cache refresh request (Cmd + Shift + R on my Mac), the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `tmp/cache` dir. It helped for me (the problem occurred after the gem update).

source: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/119